# why my spring validation annotations doesnt work

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, nosuchelementexception

i have simple for where i put one string and im using annotations to valid the value
and it doesnt work

here is my class:

```
public class Destination
{
    @NotNull
    String address;

    public Destination(){}

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

here is my controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String findDestination(@ModelAttribute("destination") @Valid Destination destination, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    Location location = LocationManager.getLocation(destination.getAddress());
    Weather weather = WeatherManager.getWeather(location);
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("weather", weather);
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("location", location);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

and here is my form in jsp file:

```
    <form:form method="post" action="search" commandName="destination" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <form:input path="address" placeholder="Enter destination address"/>
            <form:errors path="address" cssclass="error"></form:errors>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn"/>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

so the problem is that it doesnt valid my input
when i left it empty it still try to get addres for location object from null destination object and i get the exception
`HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException`

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.util.NoSuchElementException
    java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:794)
    com.springapp.mvc.domain.LocationManager.getLocation(LocationManager.java:52)
    com.springapp.mvc.controller.HomeController.findDestination(HomeController.java:51)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: Show us the exception stack trace, please.

Comment: updated my question with stack trace

Comment: I don't know why the validation doesn't happen, but the error comes, obviously, from `LocationManager.getLocation` so show us that.

Comment: maybe i imported wrong class in my destination class file for @notnull annotation ?
i imported `import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;` is it good ?
it come frome there becous it get destination.getAddress() as null value and it try to get cords for null address

Comment: I doubt it. You should have `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`.

Comment: ok i changed it but it still does the same exception
and for the @Valid annotation this is correct `import javax.validation.Valid;`?

Comment: Try to use '@Valid @ModelAttribute("destination") Destination destination'

Comment: doesnt help still the same.
how it even works ?
when the value is not valid it should enter this if ?
`if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "redirect:/";
        }`

Comment: @vardius You can also use `@NotEmpty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty html inputs when submitted are empty strings, this could be why your validation isn't working.  You can try adding the @Size annotation, i.e. `@Size(min=1)`

Comment: ok it works like that but it doesnt display the error message
i thought that there is some kind of default message witch will be displayd or its becous i do redirect ?